# Algorithm to reduce byte array image size to 1MB android

Tags: android

I want to write a Algorithm to reduce image size to around 1MB before posting data to database in android.
My image is in byte array and i have to send byte array to database.

Here is the code i am trying, but sometimes it gives out of memory exception at bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos); line.

Code:

```
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if (imgData != null) {
             if (imgData.length > 1048576) {
                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 1;
                 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, imgData.length,options);
                 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                 bm.recycle();
                 bm = null;
                 byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                 ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                 reqEntity.addPart("image_data", bab);
             } else {
                 ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imgData, "image.jpg");
                 reqEntity.addPart("image_data", bab);
             }
```

Moreover i dont want to use Bitmap.compress as i am already using BitmapFactory options.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: using 100 for the quality setting would probably result in a very large JPEG - I'd start with 90 and experiment with lower settings until you've got the right speed/quality tradeoff.

Comment: @Paul - I tried with 90, actual image size was 1.2 MB ,this time i didnot get Out of memory and image size reduced to .8 MB.    Problem is that actual image from camera comes out to be different sizes some time 1.2 MB, sometimes 1.8 MB and moreover different phones have different cameras which may give more bigger size, i was looking for a algorithm.

Comment: Well, you can do the same thing in code. Start with 90. If larger than 1MB, try lower. If smaller than 1MB and smaller than source, try larger.